# Сохранить картинку в памяти

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь сохранить картинку, чтобы при включении приложения значение сохранялось

```
var higImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var higScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var numberOfImages: NSInteger!

var Score: NSInteger!

func didMoveToView(view: SKView){
    if (Score == 1){
    numberOfImages == 1

    for var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++ {
        let angle = ((endAngleRad-startAngleRad)/Double(numberOfImages)*Double(i))+startAngleRad
        var views = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "10"))
        views.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        views.center = CGPointMake(center.x+CGFloat(R*cos(angle)), center.y+CGFloat(R*sin(angle)))
        self.view? .addSubview(views)
    }

    if (Score == 2){
    numberOfImages == 2

    for var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++ {
        let angle = ((endAngleRad-startAngleRad)/Double(numberOfImages)*Double(i))+startAngleRad
        var views = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "10"))
        views.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        views.center = CGPointMake(center.x+CGFloat(R*cos(angle)), center.y+CGFloat(R*sin(angle)))
        self.view? .addSubview(views)
    }

    if higScore.valueForKey("higScore") != nil{
        Score = higScore.valueForKey("higScore") as! NSInteger
    }
    if higImage.valueForKey("higImage") != nil{
        views = higImage.valueForKey("higImage") as! UIImageView
    }
}
```

У меня переменная Score сохраняется, а изображение - views получается нет.

Comment: что то я пытаюсь отформатировать код, и тут двух скобок не хватает. в частнисти где закрывающиеся для if (Score == 1) { и if (Score == 2) {

Comment: а можно посмотреть как вы его сохраняете. да и вообще уберите весь этот код, покажите только как сохраняете и как загружаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранение:

```
let myImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "coolImage"))
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageData, forKey: "image")
```

Загрузка:

```
let data:NSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("image") as! NSData
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data))
```

Компилировать не пробовал, вроде должно работать.

Comment: Это на objective? я не понимаючто там написано

Comment: да одинаковые ж абсолютно языки. исправил ответ

Comment: Чего-то я туплю. Не пойму как к моему коду подвязать. Это мне новые переменные создавать? или можно мои использовать?

Comment: используйте свои. вам надо взять image где там он у вас есть, в моем ответе он берется из `UIImageView` и сохранить. когда загружаете то же самое наоборот - берите свой `UIImageView` и меняйте в нем `.image`. либо добавьте код для сохранения который у вас, тогда отпишусь как это в ваш код скопировать

Comment: Сохраняю я так:
var higImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 var views = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "10"))
   if higImage.valueForKey("higImage") != nil{
        views = higImage.valueForKey("higImage") as! UIImageView
    }

Comment: А вот как выгрузить и проверить сохраняется ли не знаю

Comment: вы не можете сохранить `UIImageView` в `userDefaults`. вам надо сохранять `UIImage` и потом либо создавать новый `UIImageView` и грузить в него, либо заменять картинку в существующем `UIImageView`

Comment: то, что вы выше написали это получается создается новый UIImageView и в него грузится?

Comment: А вот смотрите, у меня есть число Score, оно сохраняется нормально. Можно так сделать, чтобы например если при загрузке приложения Score=1 то  numberOfImages = 1 (тоесть количество звезд = 1) и заново их нарисовать?

Comment: Получилось сделать, но как-то слишком уж громоздко получается:
if higScore.valueForKey("higScore") != nil{
        Score = higScore.valueForKey("higScore") as! NSInteger
Просто сюда запихал условие if (Score == 2){
    numberOfImages == 2}
    }

Comment: Может можно покороче это сделать?

Comment: у `NSUserDefaults` есть метод `integerForKey`, можно использовать его, чтобы не делать преобразование id  в integer, но этот метод возвращает 0, если ключа нет в userDefaults

Comment: Всё понял, разобрался, спасибо за помощь

Comment: ну если помогло, ставьте галочку :)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, для сохранения в **NSUserDefaults** необязательно создавать две одинаковые переменные (лучше вообще брать *константы*).

NSUserDefaults прост в использовании, но у него есть ограничение по памяти. В 1 МБ на ключ, если я не ошибаюсь, но могу соврать.

Чтобы сохранить ваше изображение, необязательно сохранять объект типа **UIImage**. Надо сохранять ее дату (*NSData*).

Для этого воспользуйтесь следующим кодом:

```
let image = вашImageView.image!
let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

И далее нужно сохранить константу **imgData**  в **NSUserDefaults**.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standartDefaults()
defaults.setObject(imgData, forKey: "savedImg") 
defaults.synchronize()
```

Теперь она в памяти. Чтобы получить ее, достаточно использовать следующие строки:

```
let imgData = defaults.objectForKey("savedImg") as? NSData
```

Я использовал опциональный тип переменной для проверки ее существования. Тут можно воспользоваться условием

```
if imgData != nil {
   //она не пустая
} else {
   //она пустая
}
```

Так Вы избежите возможного вылета.
Когда мы получили дату, мы превращаем ее обратно в **UIImage**:

```
let image = UIImage(data: imgData)
```

Готово, надеюсь помог.

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне лучший способ

```
extension String {

    func stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: String) -> String {
        let nsSt = self as NSString
        return nsSt.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
    }

}


extension UIImage {

    static func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {
        return documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    }

    static func saveImage(image: UIImage, path: String) -> Bool {
        let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let result = pngImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        return result
    }

    static func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
        let image : UIImage?
        let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
        if data == nil {
            return nil
        } else {
            image =  UIImage(data: data!)
        }
        return image
    }

}

 let path = fileInDocumentsDirectory("nameImage.png")

 UIImage.saveImage(image, path)

 //сохранили картинку

 let loadImage = loadImagFromPath(path)

 // loadImage - это и будет ваша картинка сохранённая в памяти телефон
```